# Use different size fo jumps and send data on MPI_Scatter

Tags: c, mpi

I want to send a matriz that I have in a 1d array (in rows) by columns, i tried this:
(TAM is the size of the matrix, and C the number of columns to be send to each process)

```
PI_Datatype MPI_COLUMNA;
        MPI_Type_vector(TAM, 1, TAM, MPI_DOUBLE, &MPI_COLUMNA);
        MPI_Type_create_resized( MPI_COLUMNA, 0,sizeof(double), &MPI_COLUMNA );
        MPI_Type_commit(&MPI_COLUMNA);  

        int ACTUAL=1;
        double * buffer = malloc(sizeof(double) * C * TAM);
        for (int i = 0; i < TAM; i+=C*PROCESOS){
            MPI_Scatter(&A[i], 1, MPI_COLUMNA, buffer, 
                sizeof(double) * TAM * C,                       // Tamaño del envío a cada proceso
                MPI_FLOAT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }
```

but when I try this I only get the first item, because the size of  MPI_COLUMNA is one double, but if i change it to 4 the programs fails because the Scatter jumps too much (for items, going to the next row and not to the next column, that starts in the next item).

How can i define the jump of the scatter to be one and the size of the data sent to other.

Comment: The receive type should be `MPI_DOUBLE` instead of `MPI_FLOAT`

Comment: Thank you! That and an error on the function that I used to check the receive data were all the mistakes.